# How to implement the AccountDetail of the UserAccountsDrawerHeader widget to be displayed the same as the Gmail App with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the Flutter `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` widget to display the user's data but I could not figure out how to implement the `onDetailsPressed()` function to call the user details. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildAppBar() {
  return new AppBar();
}

Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  return new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: new Text("Cleudice Santos"),
          accountEmail: new Text("cleudice.ms@gmail.com"),
          onDetailsPressed: () {},
        ),
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Visão geral"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.dashboard),
          onTap: () {
            print("Visão geral");
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I want to click the **arrow** and show the account details as shown below. That is, overlapping the content of the `drawer`. As the Gmail app does.

[image]

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing? Can you also share the code snippet and what it is you would like to achieve.

Comment: I edited my question to add the code. I could not insert it directly, so I added it to the gist.

Comment: I added your code to the question and removed the gist. You just have to paste it in, makes sure there's an empty line first, and indent it all by 4 spaces. Or paste it, select it, and press the 'code' button which inserts a line and indents it for you. Hope that helps =).

Comment: @rmtmckenzie thank you. I reduced the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, what you should be doing is replacing the rest of the content with user details rather than the current list. The simplest way to do this is to make your drawer into a stateful widget and have a boolean that keeps track of whether user details or the normal list should be shown.

I've added that to your code (and added a bit to make it self-contained so you can paste it to a new file to test out):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: UserDetailDrawer(),
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildAppBar() {
  return AppBar();
}

class UserDetailDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserDetailDrawerState createState() => _UserDetailDrawerState();
}

class _UserDetailDrawerState extends State<UserDetailDrawer> {
  bool showUserDetails = false;

  Widget _buildDrawerList() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text("Visão geral"),
          leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
          onTap: () {
            print("Visão geral");
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text("Another tile??"),
          leading: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserDetail() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text("User details"),
            leading: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(children: [
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text("Cleudice Santos"),
          accountEmail: Text("cleudice.ms@gmail.com"),
          onDetailsPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              showUserDetails = !showUserDetails;
            });
          },
        ),
        Expanded(child: showUserDetails ? _buildUserDetail() : _buildDrawerList())
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried push but could not progress. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Ah, I see what you want now that you've updated your question. I'll edit my answer, what you want is different than what that would do.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. I had not been very clear before, and I was hitting a question. Thank you very much.